# 'User already exists' en Django con 'unique=False' en Model

Tags: mysql, python, django

Este es mi model en Django

```
  class Devices(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True,null=True,unique=False)
```

Creo un registro normal con ese usuario. 
Pero cuando voy a insertar un segundo registro 'Device' en el Panel de Administración de Django con ese mismo usuario, me lo impide:

```
 Devices with this User already exists.
```

He estado buscando por todas partes pero la respuesta, quizás sea tan sencilla que no he podido encontrar nada en la documentación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si deseas crear más de un dispositivo con el mismo usuario entonces por qué `OneToOneField`? en ese caso utiliza

```
user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, ...)
```

Tu problema se encuentra en el tipo de relación que has definido, donde estableces que un dispositivo solo puede tener un usuario y viceversa, un usuario puede tener un dispositivo.